# form action not working after ajax successful

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form with file upload. I want to perform to two task:  one is data submit to the database and upload file through ajax and after ajax successful another is going to form action.ajax are work properly but after ajax successful form action is not working 
Kindly help

**main.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function mycall() {

                //disable the default form submission
                event.preventDefault();

                //grab all form data  
                var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('data'));

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'addToMySQL.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (returndata) {
                       alert(returndata);
                    }
                });

                return false;
            }
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data" id="data" action="try.php" >
            <div class="form-input">
                <label for="exampleSelect1" class="col-md-3 control-label">Type of Paper</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <select class="form-control"  id="Otop" name="Otop" required>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-input">
                    <label for="exampleSelect1" class="col-md-3 control-label">Paper upload</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <input type="file" id="file" name="profileImg" >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" onclick="mycall()" name="OrderSubmit" value="Order">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

addToMySQL.php

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include("dbconfig.php");
include('class/userClass.php');

$userClass = new userClass();

$Otop           = $_POST['Otop'];
$Odiscipline    = $_FILES['profileImg']['name']; 

$target         = "uploads/";       
$fileTarget     = $target.$Odiscipline; 

$result         = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profileImg']['tmp_name'], "uploads/".$_FILES['profileImg']['name']);

$id             = $userClass->userOrderInfo($Otop,$Odiscipline, $fileTarget);

if ($id) {
    echo "done";
} else {
    echo "Notdone";
}
```

userOrderInfo fuction in userClass.php

```
/* User Payment */
     public function userOrderInfo($Otop, $Odiscipline, $fileTarget)
     {
          try {
              $db = getDB();

              $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO orderinfo(Otop, Odiscipline, fileTarget) VALUES (:Otop, :Odiscipline, :fileTarget)");  
              $stmt->bindParam("Odiscipline", $Odiscipline) ;
              $stmt->bindParam("Otop", $Otop) ;
              $stmt->bindParam("fileTarget", $fileTarget) ;
              $stmt->execute();
              $db = null;

              return true;

          } catch(PDOException $e) {
              echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
          }
     }
```

Comment: What do you mean that it does not work? Tell us the specific details

Comment: @CamiloGo ya after ajax successful it not  go to try.php which is form action.

Comment: i don't see any element with id = data ..

Comment: @scaisEdge  var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('data')); and id="data" is mention form tag

Comment: if you don'execute the ajax call  how do you think of execute the related  success function ?

Comment: @scaisEdge kindly check above comment i execute ajax call through on submit

Comment: then you submit your form and invoke the action named  try.php .. ?  .. but i don't see this files ..

Comment: @scaisEdge ya right ..

Answer (score 1):

Ok to get this clear in my head, what your code is doing is this:

1. The form is filled out and you click "submit" which prevents form
   default action from being submitted. Instead this takes the form
   data and submits it via ajax to `addToMySQL.php`
2. `addToMySQL.php` then handles the upload of the file and calls `userOrderInfo()` on `userClass.php`
3. `userOrderInfo` will return either a `(string)` or `(boolean) true` both of which PHP will treat as `true` for the purposes of an `if()` statement.
4. `addToMySQL.php` returns a response of `(string) "done"` to `main.php`
5. The ajax call `main.php` takes the response from `addToMySQL.php` and triggers a javascript alert with the content of `"done"`.

Because of the way this has been written, the form will never use it's action property and instead will just constantly try to ajax the content of the form to `addToMySQL.php` because you are using `event.preventDefault();`.

**Solution**

A quick solution would be to either add a javascript redirect to the ajax success method, or add hidden `<form>` with the action you want to send your user to do and then populate and send it with javascript once the file has uploaded.

Whatever way you decide to do it, I would recommend fixing `addToMySQL.php`so it won't constantly send back `"done"`!

Comment: No probs @ManojMali. Please make sure to upvote and accept the answer if this helped. It will help boost my reputation ;)